# Magento Admin form

Tags: magento-1.7

I’m trying to add a country dropdown and a region dropdown in an adminhtml form.

Ideally, the region dropdown would populate via Ajax based on the selected country.

Below is my initial code:

```
$fieldset->addField('country_code', 'select', array(
     'name'      => 'country_code',
     'label'     => Mage::helper(my_module)->__('Country'),
     'values'    =>     Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_country')->toOptionArray(),
```

));

```
$fieldset->addField('region_code', 'select', array(
     'name'      => 'region_code',
     'label'     => Mage::helper('my_module')->__('Region'),
     'values'    => ?????,
     'class'   => 'ajax',
```

));

I m not very good in magento. Please help..!!! Thanks..!!